# Promise each iteration error in nodejs

Tags: node.js, iteration, promise, sails.js, bluebird

I'm trying to adopt bluebird Promise for my existing project which uses sails.js, here's the snippet:

```
    var isUserTeamCaptain = function(userId, teamId) {
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            Team.findOne({id: teamId}).then(function(team) {
                if (team) {
                    if (userId != team.captain) {
                        reject(sails.__('you are not captain, thus cannot edit team info'));
                    } else {
                        resolve(team);
                    }
                } else {
                    reject(sails.__('team not found'));
                }
            }).catch(function(err) {
                reject(err);
            });
        });
    };
    isUserTeamCaptain('5604145aa8944407362d6abf', '560496d157f6995702b3f931').then(
        function resolve(team) {
            console.log('passed');
            return Promise.resolve(User.find());
        },
        function reject(err) {
            console.log('failed');
            console.log('the error: ' + err);
            throw new Error(err);
        }
    ).each(function(user) {
        console.log(user.username);
    }).then(function() {
        console.log('we are done with each iteration')
    }).catch(function(err) {
        console.log(err.message);
    })
```

It works great, each username can be printed in console, so can 'we are done with each iteration', also in the order I expected.

BUT, if I put the isUserTeamCaptain in another js file, say 'TeamService.js', export and inject TeamService here and then refactor the above snippet of code like so:

```
    TeamService.isUserTeamCaptain('5604145aa8944407362d6abf', '560496d157f6995702b3f931').then(
        function resolve(team) {
            console.log('passed');
            return Promise.resolve(User.find());
        },
        function reject(err) {
            console.log('failed');
            console.log('the error: ' + err);
            throw new Error(err);
        }
    ).each(function(user) {
        console.log(user.username);
    }).then(function() {
        console.log('we are done with each iteration')
    }).catch(function(err) {
        console.log(err.message);
    })
```

It complains about

```
.each(function(user) { ...
```

being an UNDEFINED FUNCTION. Did I miss anything here?

UPDATE: this is the TeamService.js:

```
// TeamService.js - in api/services
var TeamService = module.exports = {
    /**
     * Promise version of isUserCaptainOfTeam
     */
    isUserTeamCaptain: function(userId, teamId) {
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            Team.findOne({id: teamId}).then(function(team) {
                if (team) {
                    if (userId != team.captain) {
                        reject(sails.__('you are not captain, thus cannot edit team info'));
                    } else {
                        resolve(team);
                    }
                } else {
                    reject(sails.__('team not found'));
                }
            }).catch(function(err) {
                reject(err);
            });
        });
    }
};
```

UPDATE: kinda found out where my problem was, I missed

```
var Promise = require('bluebird');
```

in TeamService.js...

Comment: can you share the code where you pass `isUserTeamCaptain` method between modules, also I am seeing a lot of redundant code, I would reduce your code to: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/r2nq3Ln2/)

Comment: Just did as you requested, from what I see, the isUserTeamCaptain function are identical in two situations, only in two different places.

Comment: Ok, just found out, was a stupid mistake, I should have add: var Promise = require('bluebird') in TeamService.js

Comment: good that you found out, but still, i would like to point out the problems in the code, like promise anti-pattern, and redundancy of doing `return Promise.resolve(User.find())`, when simply `return  User.find()` would suffice...

Comment: Thanks, I did try out your code snippet, yet when running, the stack trace complains it is not handling the situation when the user is NOT the team captain or when the team NOT found, how would you handle the reject in your case scenario if I may ask?

Comment: try adding `return` in front of the `Promise.reject(...`

Comment: Gotcha, really appreciate it!

Comment: stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-explicit-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it

Comment: using new Promise is a promise antipattern as pointed out by bluebird. sails.js allready creates a promise for you, so you can just return `Team.findOne({id: teamId}).then(function(team) .... `